# Hibernate Envers - pass custom field

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I have problem with Hibernate Envers. How can I pass custom fields into RevisionListener?
For example:

I have some entity with @Audit annotation, and everything works fine. But i have no idea how can i pass custom fields like "comment".

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REVINFO")
@RevisionEntity(MyRevisionEntityListener.class)
public class RevEntity {
    @Id
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column(name = "REV", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Column(name = "REVTSTMP", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date timestamp;

    @Column(name = "MODIFIED_BY", length = 100)
    private String modifiedBy;

    @Column(name = "COMMENT", length = 100)
    private String comment;
```

```
public class MyRevisionEntityListener implements RevisionListener {
    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        RevEntity a = (RevEntity) revisionEntity;
       a.setComment("");//how can i populate it?
    }
}
```

So, how can i set comment field?

Edit---------

I found some trick with ThreadLocal - but it is safe with multiple "active users" ?

For example:

```
public class CustomComment {

    public static final CustomComment INSTANCE = new CustomComment();

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> storage = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        storage.set(comment);
    }

    public String get() {
        return storage.get();
    }
}
```

And i have Service which modify entity:

```
CustomComment.INSTANCE.setComment("custom comment");
someRepository.save(someEntity);
```

Than everything works how i want.
But is this solution safe? If 2 or more ppl "change" different entities, will this work good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Than everything works how i want. But is this solution safe? If 2 or
>   more ppl "change" different entities, will this work good?

If you are performing your update within a `@Transaction` then everything within the transaction boundary will happen in the same thread, so you're all good.

Comment: Thanks :) One more thing, is there any "easy" solution to select "every" ```RevEntity``` for desirable Entity ID ?

Comment: You're welcome :) I can't think of an "easy" solution because all the audit tables reference the pk on the `revision_info` table but there won't be any foreign keys otherwise you couldn't delete anything. `org.hibernate.envers.AuditReader` might have some of what you want but won't do that.